# Как заставить нейросеть классифицировать текст?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

```
Нужно классифицировать математические задачи по номерам.
То есть, нужно чтоб нейросеть определяла, что задача X относится к типу Y.
Я имею следующий код: https://pastebin.com/7whhZWKT  
файл train.csv для обучающей выборки: https://pastebin.com/29NHZFB5  
файл test.csv для тестовой: https://pastebin.com/VpGv9bFV.  
Я думаю, что по сути я сам определяю класс задачи(я могу ошибаться).  
Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне заставить нейросеть самой классифицировать задачи?
```

[image: график]

Comment: Ч то-то очень странное -  в вашем коде комментарии "# Максимальная длина новости", "# Количество классов новостей" а в вопросе "классифицировать математические задачи по номерам". Что-то одно с другим не вяжется. Про то, что в одном наборе у вас все объекты с первой меткой "1", а во втором - с "4" - я просто молчу. Чему на таком наборе вы собрались учить свою нейросеть?

Comment: по поводу комментариев не заморачивайтесь, там много копипаста
подскажите как мне поправить ситуацию? я новичок в нейросетях @passant

Comment: По предоставленной вами информации - понятия не имею. Тем более, если задача не совпадает с кодом, который вы почему-то решили для нее применять.  Может, проще сначала что-нибудь про нейросети прочитать самому? А уж потом, когда что-то станет неясным идти на форум с конкретным вопросом?

Comment: @passant, тоже верно, думаю я действительно забежал вперед. нужно по лучше разобраться

Answer (score 1):

У вас в `train` только один класс `1`:

```
train['class'].value_counts()
# 1    88
```

Для того, чтобы модель чему-то обучилась в трейне должны быть представлены все классы, которым вы хотите обучить её. Вот в тесте у вас два класса - `1` и `4`.

Ну и в целом для нейросетей нужно гораздо больше данных. На таком маленьком количестве примеров нейросеть скорее всего просто переобучится и не будет показывать хороших результатов на тесте.

**UPDATE после обновления вопроса**

В итоге удалось починить процесс обучения такой магической строчкой сразу после загрузки train из файла:

```
train = train.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Дело в том, что, видимо, нейросеть во время обучения разбивает данные на трейн и валидацию в том порядке, как они идут в датафрейме, не перемешивая, а в файле лейблы данных шли в строгом порядке от 1 до 19. В результате получалось обучение на одних лейблах, а валидация на других.
Оказалось достаточно перемешать train случайным образом, и нейросеть начала учиться нормально на всех лейблах.

Comment: Спасибо, а как правильно протестировать нейросеть и проверить ее на конкретном примере после обучения? Например, я на вход подаю ей задачу, а она определяет ее класс.

Comment: @Konsul_557 Так у вас во второй части кода как-раз натренированная сетка тестируется на `test.csv`, ну вы можете и из одной строки `test` сделать, или из самого `test` взять одну строку.

Comment: ааа, понял. тогда еще вопрос. больше синтаксический, как мне получить от нейросети ответ что данная задача относится к данному классу?

Comment: @Konsul_557 Вроде рекомендуется так: `np.argmax(model_cnn.predict(x_test), axis=-1)` но вообще я в подготовке данных для нейросетей не очень разбираюсь, мне кажется у вас там всё-таки не совсем всё в порядке в целом, не только в одном классе в `train` проблема.

Comment: я увеличил файл train до 3344 записей и добавил туда все 19 классов. О чем могут говорить вот такие результаты?

Epoch 00050: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.26866
11/11 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 6.8050 - accuracy: 0.6579
хотел приложить скриншот графика, но форум не дает @CrazyElf

Comment: @Konsul_557 В сам вопрос можно всё добавлять и скриншот и всё что угодно. Но так навскидку сложно сказать, обучение нейросетей это непростая штука

Comment: Добавил график @CrazyElf

Comment: @Konsul_557 Судя по графику могу сказать, что либо нейросети мало имеющихся данных, либо данные в трейн и в тест сильно разные. Нейросеть явно переобучается на трейне, отлично его выучивает уже за пару эпох, но на тесте тотально фейлится. Либо данные для теста подготавливаются не так, как для трейна, и поэтому такой фейл, надо код проверять.

Comment: можно с вами проконсультироваться вне форума?